# The Re and Im of complex numbers

Tags: complex-numbers

While solving this assigment : $\Re z + \Im(z*z) = 2$, I easily get this equation : $a + 2ab  = 2$ ( where I start from $z = a+bi$), but I don't know what do to do next, any formula I use brings me to the same point. If anyone can help, I would be thankful.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Consider using `z\cdot z` $z\cdot z$, `z\times z` $z\times z$, or simply `z^2` $z^2$ instead of `z*z` $z*z$, which is all too similar to one of the notations for complex conjugation, especially when you originally posted your question not using MathJax.

Answer (score 2):

It should be $$a+2ab=2,$$
which gives $b=\frac{2-a}{2a}$ and $z=a+\frac{2-a}{2a}i$.

Also, in your assuming $z=a+bi$ you need to say that $\{a,b\}\subset\mathbb R$.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing more to say. If $z=a+bi$, then $z$ satisfies the equation $$\mathrm{Re}(z) +\mathrm{Im}(z\cdot z) = 2$$

if and only if $$a+2ab=2.$$

The equation determines the set of all possible values of $z$ (there are infinitely many).

Answer (score 0):

If $z^*= \overline{z}$, then

$z^*z=|z|^2 \in \mathbb R$, hence your equation reduces to $\Re z =2$.

Comment: I believe there was a miscommunication: after using MathJax, it appears that the OP intends for $*$ to stand for multiplication, not complex conjugation.